# Video.js run a function on pause that display an iframe

Tags: function, api, iframe, video.js

I was reading about video.js api and I was wondering if it's possible to call with ready function, when video is paused, a php page embed with iframe?
Thanks!
Ex:

```
var myPlayer = videojs("session_video");

  videojs("session_video").ready(function(){

  this.on("paused", function(){
    the php embed with iframe
  });

});
```

Edit: Thanks to heff I managed to get it working.
Here is the code:

```
videojs("session_video").ready(function(){



var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = '<iframe src="http://www.company.com/show.php" width="300" height="250" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="position:absolute;" left: 50%; margin-left:-WIDTHOFBANNER; top: 50%; margin-top:-HEIGHTOFBANNER;></iframe>';

  var ifrm = div.firstChild;

  this.on("pause", function(){
    this.el().appendChild(ifrm);
  });

  this.on("play", function(){
    this.el().removeChild(ifrm);
  });

});
```

Comment: What does the PHP embed look like? The rest of the code should work. You could try `var ifrm = document.createElement('iframe'); this.el().appendChild(ifrm);`. If you just embed HTML there it won't work. It needs to be added with javascript.

Comment: I can't access the php file. I was given the code from one of the sponsors and it looks like this:
`<iframe src="http://www.company.com/show.php" width="300" height="250" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe> 
`
It displays a 300x250 banner just like a image ad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure as far as the dom operations, but this should work for the Video.js API

```
videojs("session_video").ready(function(){

  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = '<iframe src="http://www.company.com/show.php" width="300" height="250" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>';

  var ifrm = div.firstChild;

  this.on("pause", function(){
    this.el().appendChild(ifrm);
  });

  this.on("play", function(){
    this.el().removeChild(ifrm);
  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! the code works well but I have 2 problems. The iframe is shown behind the video and it would it can't be clicked.(probably from "play" argument)If i click on the banner the video resumes.Thanks
I removed all the plugins just to be sure neither interfere with the function.

Comment: try adding style="position:absolute;" on the iframe

Comment: Perfect. Now the banner is on the video and clickable. Final question: How can I change it's position. Here is a ss with the current position:http://imgur.com/SZmhm1L
Is it possible to place in the middle?

Comment: add to the style attribute "left: 50%; margin-left:-WIDTHOFBANNER; top: 50%; margin-top:-HEIGHTOFBANNER;" Replace the words in caps as described, and keep the negative sign in front. (Also don't forget to accept the answer if it works for you, please.)